# Caldeira-Leggett dissipation model: Call for Help!

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am sorry to be so troublesome and possibly infringing some rules, but could I once more invoke the help of other participants in order to solve my query on the Caldeira-Legget model, namely the introduction of a phase shift, better detailed in [Caldeira-Leggett Dissipation: frequency shift due to bath coupling](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/100041/caldeira-legget-dissipation-cannot-get-it)?

Thank you very much. I am so keen to understand this point but got into a "loop" and cannot make sense of it any more...

Comment: I accept your decision QMechanics and the site's rules, but it is incorrect to state my question has been answered already, as it has not. Otherwise I would have continued on that thread and not started a new one.

Comment: True, the default closing banner text sometimes does not fit well. The usual way of promoting your question is through a [bounty](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4961/2451) once you have a bit more reputation. To that end, I upvoted your original question.